# Getting large amounts of bounding boxes around cities and natural land coverages

Tags: qgis, extents

I am an astronomy student working on a research project in which I want to get large amounts of bounding boxes around cities and natural land coverages. In QGIS, I am using a dataset of Europe that gives the different land coverages (types of forest, cities, beaches, you name it) and of course the option to turn those on or off in display.

I would very much like to automate the process of selecting a certain land coverage type, and retrieving a whole bunch of BBox values (maybe within a certain subset of the entire dataset) to then use in my research. I would very much like to ask if any of you good give me any headers about what route to take to achieve this.

I am used to working with Python, and I think that writing a Python script is maybe a way to go about this? I am completely new to working with GIS, and hope this is the right place to ask.

Comment: Have you tried the tool `boundingboxes`? If so, how does it not suit your needs?

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE! Is your land coverages dataset vector (e.g. shapefile) or raster (e.g. tiff) data? You could use either `ogr` or `gdal` to accomplish this from a stand alone Python script.

Comment: I have not used the tool boundingboxes, as I was unaware of it. I might have to look that up! Also, I am using vector data. I think these mentions are things to look at!

Comment: @Erik, the problem is that I want to automate the process of manually selecting a polygon of which I'll then automatically get the bounding box. I want to input the land coverage class and have output a .csv file (or something similar) with bounding box coordinates of many polygons of that coverage class.